# Traversing a nested hierarchy of any depth from bottom - up

Tags: c#, .net, json, recursion

Take a nested recursive JSON snippet like this that can go on to any depth:

```
{
   "Id": null,
   "Foos": [
      {
         "FooId": 1,
         "FooName": "ABC",
         "Foos": [
            {
               "FooId": 2,
               "FooName": "DEF",
               "Foos": null
            },
            {
               "FooId": 3,
               "FooName": "GHI",
               "Foos": [
                  {
                     "FooId": 4,
                     "FooName": "JKL",
                     "Foos": null
                  },
                  {
                     "FooId": 5,
                     "FooName": "MNO",
                     "Foos": [
                        {
                           "FooId": 6,
                           "FooName": "PQR",
                           "Foos": null
                        },
                        {
                           "FooId": 7,
                           "FooName": "STU",
                           "Foos": null
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Using JSON.NET I can map that into a structure like this:

```
public class Root {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Foo {
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

so far so good...but now I need to work from the bottom of the hierarchy upward (starting with the children at FooId=5) and then working my way back up to the root. How do I tackle this efficiently?

Comment: Would it be bad if you iterate the tree once after deserialization?

Comment: To clarify, you wish to iterate the objects in the order 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1?

Comment: What if we have the tree `A [ B [ C, D ] , E [ F, G ] ] `? Do you want C, D, B, F, G, E, A?  Or do you want C, D, F, G, B, E, A ? The first is post-order traversal, the second is level traversal, and they are very different. It's not clear from your question which you need.

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal and say more clearly which traversal you want.

Comment: Or, do you really just want to walk up the parents of the `FooId": 5` node, similarly to how [`XElement.AncestorsAndSelf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.ancestorsandself?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [`JToken.AncestorsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_AncestorsAndSelf.htm) enumerate the parents of a given node?  E.g. the ancestors would be `5, 3, 1, null`

Comment: @EricLippert "To clarify, you wish to iterate the objects in the order 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1? "  

Precisely

Comment: You say that the tree can be "any depth". **Be more specific**. I work on systems where such trees can have billions of nodes. Are you worried about the case where there are billions of nodes in your tree? In that case you have a big problem on your hands and should consider investing in a big-data solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear from your question whether you want a postorder (depth-first) traversal, or a reverse level traversal (breadth-first, reversed). Assuming you want postorder, the algorithm is straightforward:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Postorder<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> nodes,
  Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children)
{
  foreach(T node in nodes)
  {
    foreach(T descendant in children(node).Postorder(children))
      yield return descendant;
    yield return node;
  }
}
```

Every node is yielded only after all of its descendants, so this is a postorder traversal.

That's reasonably efficient if the tree is shallow, but you say you wish to solve the problem for a tree of "any depth". **This approach will only work efficiently for trees of depths up to a few dozen levels** because it is O(nd) where n is the total number of nodes and d is the average depth; the average depth depends on the branching factor, and so could be as low as 1 or as high as n, making this a potentially quadradic algorithm.

Moreover, since it uses O(dmax) stack space where dmax is the maximum depth, we can blow the call stack.

Thus: if you have hundreds or thousands of levels, use the explicit stack technique.

**Exercise**: Rewrite my algorithm to use an explicit stack rather than using the call stack as an implicit stack.

But you said you need trees of *any depth*.  What if there are billions, or trillions of nodes in the tree, billions or trillions deep? In that case you'll need to go with an external memory solution, and I would recommend building a custom storage system dedicated to this problem; do some research on at-scale graph databases, which can solve this sort of problem.

Anyways, now that you have the general solution, your specific solution is straightforward:

```
var ids = root.Foos
              .Postorder(f => f.Foos)
              .Select(f => f.FooId)
              .ToList();
```

or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, that helps clarify some things.Realistically I don't need probably more than a half a dozen levels of depth in the tree so this should work fine. I can always cap the input at a reasonable amount

Comment: This is an extremely elegant answer